# What is the environment variable for AppData in NSIS installer script?

Tags: installation, nsis, appdata

I am looking for the environment variable for AppData in NSIS. I need to copy fils to the AppData directory in my installation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It can't be easier than this `$APPDATA`, you can do something like this:

```
SetShellVarContext all
!define INSTDIR_DATA "$APPDATA\MyApp" ; call "SetShellVarContext all" before!
```

Comment: Perfect. I found this link as well, if someone wants to read more: http://wilsont3ch.com/about-portables-2/more-file-management/

Answer (score 8):

**$APPDATA** is already defined as constant in NSIS.

The application data directory. Detection of the current user path requires Internet Explorer 4 and above. Detection of the all users path requires Internet Explorer 5 and above. The context of this constant (All Users or Current user) depends on the SetShellVarContext setting. The default is the current user.